# C# Unhandled Exception using try catch block

Tags: c#, exception, webexception

I'm getting a `System.Net.WebException` saying:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

This is what I'm expecting since invalid headers are being passed in with the http request. However, my code does not seem to be catching the exception like I would expect.

Here is the code:

```
private void callback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Callback");
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) 
                       as HttpWebResponse;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + e);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Unknown exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

Why is the exception not caught?

Comment: Does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692342/net-httpwebrequest-getresponse-raises-exception-when-http-status-code-400-ba

Comment: Probably because of this asynchronous thing where different things happen on different threads?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689493/catching-exceptions-from-asynchronous-httpwebrequest-calls-in-a-task).

Probably you should do something like this:

```
Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    request.BeginGetResponse,
    asyncResult => { callback(asyncResult); },
    (object)null);

return task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
if (t.IsFaulted)
{
    //handle error
    Exception firstException = t.Exception.InnerExceptions.First();
}
else
{
    return FinishWebRequest(t.Result);
}
});
```