# Asynchronous QueryQueuedBuilds

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, tfs

Our program uses the QueryQueuedBuilds from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server to get all the queued builds from our build server.

So far we did it synchrone from a DispatcherTimer tick method, but the UI gets non-responsive sometimes for more than 1000 ms. This is the original call:

```
    public List<QueuedBuild> GetQueuedBuilds()
    {
        List<QueuedBuild> queuedBuilds = new List<QueuedBuild>();

        foreach (var project in _teamProjectList)
        {
            IQueuedBuildSpec queuedBuildSpec = _buildServer.CreateBuildQueueSpec(project.Name);
            IQueuedBuildQueryResult queuedBuildQueryResult = _buildServer.QueryQueuedBuilds(queuedBuildSpec);

            if (queuedBuildQueryResult.QueuedBuilds.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var result in queuedBuildQueryResult.QueuedBuilds)
                {
                    queuedBuilds.Add(new QueuedBuild()
                    {
                     // Set properties from result
                    });
                }
            }                
        }

        return queuedBuilds;
    }
```

But the line with the QueryQueuedBuilds takes a long time.

I discovered there are asynchronous methods BeginQueryQueuedBuilds and EndQueryQueuedBuilds, but I cannot find examples how to use it. This is what I got so far:

```
public List<QueuedBuild> GetQueuedBuilds()
{
    List<QueuedBuild> queuedBuilds = new List<QueuedBuild>();
    Collection<IQueuedBuildSpec> queuedBuildSpecs = new Collection<IQueuedBuildSpec>();

    foreach (var project in _teamProjectList)
    {
        queuedBuildSpecs.Add(_buildServer.CreateBuildQueueSpec(project.Name));
    }

    IAsyncResult asyncResult = _buildServer.BeginQueryQueuedBuilds(queuedBuildSpecs.ToArray(),
        OnBeginQueryQueuedBuilds, queuedBuilds);
    
    // What to do with asyncResult?

    return queuedBuilds; // How to return queuedBuilds?
}

private void OnBeginQueryQueuedBuilds(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if (!(ar.AsyncState is List<QueuedBuild> queuedBuilds))
    {
        return;
    }

    IQueuedBuildQueryResult[] queryResults = _buildServer.EndQueryQueuedBuilds(ar);

    foreach (var queuedBuildQueryResult in queryResults)
    {
        foreach (var result in queuedBuildQueryResult.QueuedBuilds)
        {
            queuedBuilds.Add(new QueuedBuild()
            {
                // Set properties from result
            });
        }
    }

    // How to get the queuedBuilds back to the GUI?
}
```

The callback method works. But how do I get the queuedBuilds back to my GUI?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? There are modern asynchronous APIs available in versions of TFS released in the past 7 years.

Comment: We just upgraded to ADS2020. So I should use another API?

Comment: Yes. You're using the old SOAP libraries that haven't been updated for years. There are REST libraries using modern APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#rest-packages

Comment: @DanielMann I found out that this piece of code is for getting the old XAML builds (we still have a lot of them). My collegue told me he used this old API especially for the XAML builds, coz the new WebApi didn't support XAML builds, only vNext. Is that true?

Comment: No, there are REST APIs for XAML builds. I don't know if they're exposed in the REST API client versus having to construct REST API calls by hand, and I can't vouch for how well they work, but they do exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

That said, XAML builds have been deprecated for **seven years**. It's really in your best interest to migrate them to something modern.

Comment: Yes, I know. But we have almost 200 of them. There isn't a XAML to YAML converter. It all has to be done by hand. And that takes time. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the puzzle similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13689693/1770778) solution.

Most important changes I did:
The callback method isn't used anymore.
The `IAsyncResult` is now passed to a `Task.Factory.FromAsync()` method and the task is awaited.

This is what I ended up with:

```
    public async Task<List<QueuedBuild>> GetQueuedBuilds()
    {
        Collection<IQueuedBuildSpec> queuedBuildSpecs = new Collection<IQueuedBuildSpec>();

        foreach (var project in _teamProjectList)
        {
            queuedBuildSpecs.Add(_buildServer.CreateBuildQueueSpec(project.Name));
        }

        IAsyncResult asyncResult = _buildServer.BeginQueryQueuedBuilds(queuedBuildSpecs.ToArray(), null, null);

        var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, _buildServer.EndQueryQueuedBuilds);
        IQueuedBuildQueryResult[] queuedBuildQueryResults = await task;
        return FinishQueryQueuedBuilds(queuedBuildQueryResults);
    }

    private List<QueuedBuild> FinishQueryQueuedBuilds(IQueuedBuildQueryResult[] queuedBuildQueryResults)
    {
        List<QueuedBuild> queuedBuilds = new List<QueuedBuild>();

        foreach (var queuedBuildQueryResult in queuedBuildQueryResults)
        {
            foreach (var result in queuedBuildQueryResult.QueuedBuilds)
            {
                queuedBuilds.Add(new QueuedBuild()
                {
                    // Set properties from result
                });
            }
        }

        return queuedBuilds;
    }
```

I hope this can help someone else with a similar problem.